# Use namedPipe or UDP?

Tags: c#, udp, named-pipes

I have two process that are running on same machine and i need to have some communication between them.

This communication can be done by using namedPipe or using UDP.
I don't know what will be more effective to use.

What are the advantages of namedPipe and What are the advantages of the UDP ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try both and pick the one that best suit your needs. We don't have your specific environment. Moreover, 'effective' is _really_ broad.

Comment: Opinion based...Note that "named pipe vs TCP" may be fair comparison as both provide guaranteed delivery, pipes vs UDP seem pretty arbitrary and should trivial to choose based on requirements.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you should stick to named pipes. In contrast to UDP, named pipes DO guarantee the delivery of your packects. UDP does not provide any feedback related to the transmission. It's just fire and forget. Also, you can do some cool stuff with the permissions for the named pipes, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you must guarantee the data,NamedPipe is better.UDP do not monitor the data if it is send to other process successfully.You also can communicate with Share Memory.Write a demo and test it is important.